# Comportamiento inesperado con istringstream iss

Tags: c++, string

Básicamente tengo este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    char car;
    std::istringstream iss;
    {
        std::string buffer = "hola";
        std::istringstream iss(buffer);
        iss.get(car);
        std::cout << car << std::endl;
        iss.get(car);
        std::cout << car << std::endl;
        iss.get(car);
        std::cout << car << std::endl;
    }
    iss.get(car);
    std::cout << car << std::endl;
}
```

Esperaba que la salida fuera:

```
h
o
l
a
```

Pero me encuentro con que es:

```
h
o
l
l
```

Y no entiendo porqué. Cada vez que hago iss.get(car) estoy agarrando un carácter del flujo iss, poniéndolo en car, y sacándolo de dicho flujo, ¿cierto?. Entonces esperaría a la 4ta vez obtener la 'a', no obtener la 'l' de vuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes **2** variables distintas `iss`.

1. Creas una variable `iss` **sin inicializar**.
2. Entras en un nuevo ámbito.

   3. Creas una nueva variable `iss`<sup>2</sup> **inicializada** con una cadena. Dentro de este ámbito, cualquier uso de `iss` se refiere a esta nueva variable.
   4. Extraes un carácter de `iss`<sup>2</sup> (`car == 'h'`).
   5. Extraes un carácter de `iss`<sup>2</sup> (`car == 'o'`).
   6. Extraes un carácter de `iss`<sup>2</sup> (`car == 'l'`).
3. Sales del ámbito local. A partir de aquí, cualquier uso de `iss` se refiere a la variable **sin inicializar**.
4. Intentas leer un carácter de la variable `iss`.
5. Como `iss` no está inicializada, no se extrae ningún caracter, con lo que el valor de `car` **no cambia**, manteniendo su valor anterior (`car == 'l'`).

Y por eso te muestra repetido el carácter `'l'`.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, revisemos tu código:

```
std::istringstream iss;
{
    std::string buffer = "hola";
    std::istringstream iss(buffer);
```

Las llaves luego de `std::istringstream iss` son innecesarias, y encima, estás redeclarando el mismo stream `iss` dentro de las mismas.

Debes declarar cada variable una vez, y en el orden correcto. Te propongo un ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    char car;
    string buffer("hola");
    istringstream iss(buffer);
```

Donde cambié `string buffer = "hola"` por `string buffer("hola")` porque produce el mismo resultado.

También, puedes hacer uso de `using namespace std` después de los `#include`. Esto, para evitarte el tener que estar escribiendo `std::` cada vez.

Con esto, el resto del código está bien:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char car;
    string buffer("hola");
    istringstream iss(buffer);
    
    iss.get(car);
    cout << car << std::endl;
    iss.get(car);
    cout << car << std::endl;
    iss.get(car);
    cout << car << std::endl;
    iss.get(car);
    cout << car << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "Las llaves luego de std::istringstream iss son innecesarias". En este programa sí. Pero las puse porque refleja la situación en otro programa que estoy haciendo donde sí son necesarias (ya que hay una parte que queda dentro de un if). 
"También, puedes hacer uso de using namespace std después de los #include. Esto, para evitarte el tener que estar escribiendo std:: cada vez.". En mi caso nunca pongo eso de "using namespace std" para evitar la colisión de nombres con mis funciones.